# Make podcasts available through app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

Please make it possible to access the Stack Overflow podcast from the iOS app. Thanks!

Comment: It's available on the [iTunes Store](https://itun.es/sg/ownN9.c)

Comment: Right, but the UI isn't great, podcasts are listed in some unknown sort order, and the latest podcast isn't available there as soon as it is on the web.  I was hoping that perhaps the app could simply provide a link to the current podcast.

Comment: To the down-voters, please consider that phone apps are typically all about making life simpler for their users.  This would certainly make it easier for those of us that don't typically listen to podcasts to access the Stack Overflow podcast.  I'm not sure the level of difficulty of implementing this request, but if it's not too difficult to do, why not add it as a feature?

Comment: Yup, there're a lot of feature that the mobile app & mobile site lacks. (P.S. I didn't downvote)

Comment: This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.  Right. /s

Comment: @Panda - I agree with your assessment, but accessing the podcast in the app, while traveling using your mobile device seems a useful use case to me.

Comment: (Not the downvoter, but) [voting on meta is different, especially on feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: @qwer - Thanks for your comment.  I see your point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm kinda half-and-half on this.

Why? Well true, the UI of the Stack Exchange podcasts is weird but still usable. I think that if the podcasts were added to the app, there would be no space for anything else and everything would be just cluttered. I see no more space for them at this period. I mean, you could add it as a site but it isn't, it's a blog. You could also try the HNQ... no space there. As I said before, no space for them.

How would it be more convenient? Sure, I guess it could be more accessible but there are other options like the app for iTunes and Android and this very convenient [SoundCloud playlist](https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange) with all the podcasts in order from newest at the top and oldest and the bottom. And if I remember correctly, SoundCloud has an app.

For more "information", you can visit the [Stack Overflow Podcast](https://stackoverflow.com/podcast) page itself. Or if you want to listen to a podcast like now, you can visit the [SoundCloud playlist](https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange). And no, I am not sponsoring SoundCloud nor or they sponsoring this (that I know of :))

Comment: I think that there would be room on the menu to place another item that would link to the latest podcast - it already scrolls.  Thanks Anthony, I'll check out that SoundCloud playlist.